# java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 3C787364

Tags: xsd, xml-parsing, java-7, xsd-validation, xsd2code

I am getting this error when converting inputStream into ObjectInputStream.
Please help me regarding this.

My Code:

```
InputStream isSchema = Thread.currentThread()
                    .getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("schema.xsd");
            ObjectInputStream inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(isSchema);
```

Exception:

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 3C787364
```

Comment: Have you solved this problem? If you have solve it, How have you done?

Comment: For my requirement, i made to work with InputStream object. ObjectInputStream object is not required for my case. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Please add an answer in order to close this topic :)

Answer (score 1):

`3C787364` in hexadecimal is `<xsd` .

`schema.xsd` is not a file of serialized objects previously written using an `ObjectOutputStream`. You must use `InputStreamReader`.

***Just an example***

```
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("c:\\data\\input.txt");
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);

int data = reader.read();
while(data != -1){
    char theChar = (char) data;
    data = reader.read();
}

reader.close();
```

Comment: "3C787364 in hexadecimal is <xsd ."
@Xstian - you have no idea how much time you saved me. I was getting this error through several layers of REST service indirection. Once I saw that I realized, "AH! This other service is returning an HTML doc because it's in an error state!" It wasn't obvious from the debugging info I had, but your answer made it obvious. Super kudos. I'd upvote you twice if I could.